# Is there any trick about $\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+k^2u=\frac{u^2}{h^2}$ ？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Obviously, 
$$
\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+k^2u=\frac{u^2}{h^2}
$$
is a nonlinear 2-order ODE. Generally, it has not  formal solution. But it is a exercises on my friend's book, so, whether there is any trick about it ?

Comment: There is the constant solution $u = k^2h^2$

Comment: @NinadMunshi  Do you know any nontrival solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Set $y = \frac{du}{d\theta}$ and note that $\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} = y\frac{dy}{du}$

Comment: @BrianMoehring  Thanks,  you are right.

Comment: Can you tell us about the content of the chapter or section that this text book exercise belongs to? Are there examples for the intended solution method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $u'\neq 0$, we have that

$$u'u'' = \frac{u^2u'}{h^2} - k^2 uu' \implies u'^2 = \frac{2u^3}{3h^2} - k^2u^2$$

and further assuming that $u',u>0$

$$\int d\theta = \theta + C = \int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{\frac{2}{3h^2}u-k^2}}$$

Let $u = \frac{3h^2k^2}{2}\cosh^2t$:

$$= \int \frac{2\cosh t\sinh tdt}{|k|\cosh^2 t \sinh t} = \frac{2}{|k|}\sec^{-1}(\cosh t) = \frac{2}{|k|}\sec^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2u}{3h^2k^2}}\right)$$

Then we have

$$ u = \frac{3h^2k^2}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\theta+C}{2|k|^{-1}}\right)$$

If we had made the sign choice that $u' < 0$, then

$$u = \frac{3h^2k^2}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{-\theta+C}{2|k|^{-1}}\right)$$

Make $u<0$ doesn't quite make sense since it would make $u$ complex, and complex numbers don't have an ordering on them. That doesn't mean you aren't allowed to pull out a factor of $i$ from the integrand and integrate anyway, though.

Comment: The first implication is wrong, you are missing the integration constant.

Comment: @LutzL you are right. I think I see an easy fix, however. The factor of $|k|$ should map to $|\sqrt{k^2-D}|$ in the solutions I have. This is also not a full general solution so I'm not too concerned with considering other cases since they don't seem to follow a nice structure and we get a nontrivial solution as desired.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would arrive at that formula, you can not extract $u^2$ from the cubic $\frac{2u^3}{3h^2}-k^2u^2+D$. I'm quite certain that you do not get elementary expressions for the solution for $D\ne 0$.

Comment: @LutzL ah good point! I give up

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+k^2u=\frac{u^2}{h^2}$$
Multipli by $2\frac{du}{dt}$ on both sides and integrate, then we have
$$2\frac{du}{dt} \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+2k^2 u\frac{du}{dt}= \frac{2}{h^2}u^2 \frac{du}{dt} \implies \left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)^2+k^2u^2=\frac{2}{3h^2}u^3+B$$ Next, we get
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3h^2}u^3-k^2u^2+B}\implies \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{2u^3}{3h^2}-k^2 u^2+B}}=\pm\int dt+C$$ Here $B$ and $C$ are constants of integration which will be determined by the given initial conditions.

Comment: Sorry, please see the new edit.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it now..